# Using Set Z-Values in QGIS Processing Modeler

Tags: qgis, clip, z-value

I have a set of contours that I am trying to automate a process on. This process clips the contours by a boundary, sets z-values based on the elevation field, and then exports those contours as a dxf file to be used in CAD. My issue is that I cannot figure out how to set the Z-value from the Processing Modeler algorithm.

Is there a certain syntax that I need to use so that I can assign the `"ELEV"` field from the output of my clip function to the Z-value in the Set Z-value function? I see no drop down or option to select a field from the output of the clip function so I am confused as to how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of the field,
you can use an `expression` with the field name set as default, just select `edit`, and you'll get an expression builder window.

[image]

Otherwise, you can use a pre calculated value and set it from a field you can connect to your selected layer

[image]

[image]

The end result (just for this part) looks like this, where the `Vector Field` is connected to the `Vector Layer` and `Set Z-Values` uses them both.

[image]