# Using Set Z Value in QGIS Graphical Modeler - Modeler not passing elevations from field

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am trying to use the **Set Z Value** algorithm in QGIS Graphical Modeler. More specifically, I would like to set the elevations using values contained in a field in the input layer, but the elevations are not getting passed to the output.

I have tried connecting things as described in this post: [Using Set Z-Values in QGIS Processing Modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379000/using-set-z-values-in-qgis-processing-modeler), but Modeler is not passing any elevations to the output.

I have created the [Vector Layer] and [Vector Field] inputs as shown in the post.

In the [Set Z value] algorithm dialog, I have tried:

1. setting the [Input layer] type to [Model Input] and the value to my [Vector Layer], and
2. setting the [Input Layer] type to [Value] and setting the value to the corresponding layer name.

When I run the model, it prompts me to select the appropriate elevation field, which I do. The model runs and produces a result, but the result is not elevated. Any thoughts?

[image: Model Diagram][image: Set Z Setup][image: Model Dialog]

Comment: I only can confirm this behaviour, but I have no clue as to why it is as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **Z value** setting of the **Set Z Value** algorithm, set a **Value** (instead of a **Pre-calculated Value**).

The value starts with something like 0.000000.

Press the **data defined override** button, **Edit...** option. It will open the expression string builder. Write the following expression:

`attribute( @ElevField )`

Comment: Thanks Gabriel! That works wonderfully and helps me better understand the way Modeler works!

Comment: You are welcome, GSC.